# Lilygo ttgo t-beam and Lora problem on sending or receiving

Tags: arduino, iot, esp32, lora

is it possible to send a lora payload from a T-Beam and receive it from a LoRa32 SX1276 OLED (v2) ? I if follow those two tutorials:
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/ttgo-lora32-sx1276-arduino-ide/ or https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-lora-rfm95-transceiver-arduino-ide/, i can send and receive without problem from two LoRa32 devices.

But if i let the LoRa32 receiver ON and tries to send from a T-Beam T22V1.0, nothing seems to happen.

T-beam code: (some gps related vars are set but i removed gps code for clarity. GPS does work fine.)

What am i doing wrong ?

(if i am not in the good place for that kind of beginner issue, please tell me and i'll try to find a more suitable place for this..)

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <axp20x.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

#define SCK     5    // GPIO5  -- SX1278's SCK
#define MISO    19   // GPIO19 -- SX1278's MISnO
#define MOSI    27   // GPIO27 -- SX1278's MOSI
#define SS      18   // GPIO18 -- SX1278's CS
#define RST     23   // GPIO14 -- SX1278's RESET
#define DI0     26   // GPIO26 -- SX1278's IRQ(Interrupt Request)
#define BAND  868E6

TinyGPSPlus gps;
HardwareSerial GPS(1);
AXP20X_Class axp;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin(21, 22);
  if (!axp.begin(Wire, AXP192_SLAVE_ADDRESS)) {
    Serial.println("AXP192 Begin PASS");
  } else {
    Serial.println("AXP192 Begin FAIL");
  }
  axp.setPowerOutPut(AXP192_LDO2, AXP202_ON); //lora
  axp.setPowerOutPut(AXP192_LDO3, AXP202_ON); //gps
  axp.setPowerOutPut(AXP192_DCDC2, AXP202_ON); 
  axp.setPowerOutPut(AXP192_EXTEN, AXP202_ON);
  axp.setPowerOutPut(AXP192_DCDC1, AXP202_ON); //oled
  GPS.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, 34, 12);   //17-TX 18-RX

  SPI.begin(SCK,MISO,MOSI,SS);
  LoRa.setPins(SS,RST,DI0);
  if (!LoRa.begin(BAND)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }else{
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa succeed!");
  }

  axp.setChgLEDMode(AXP20X_LED_BLINK_1HZ);

}

void loop()
{
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("Hello");  
  LoRa.endPacket();
  Serial.println("sent..");

  delay(1000);
}
```

Thanks :)

[EDIT]

I tried to use https://github.com/Extentsoftware/TBeamPower.

Still nothing.
Here is the code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>         // https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa/blob/master/API.md
#include "gps.h"
#include "TBeamPower.h"

TBeamPower power(PWRSDA, PWRSCL); //21 22

void setupSerial() { 
  Serial.println();
  power.print_wakeup_reason();
}

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);

  Serial.println("Power begin");
  power.begin();

  Serial.println("All sensors off");
  power.power_sensors(false);

  Serial.println("All peripherals off");
  power.power_peripherals(false);

  Serial.println("Powering LoRa");
  power.power_LoRa(true);

  SPI.begin(SCK,MISO,MOSI,SS); //5 19 27 18
  LoRa.setPins(SS,RST,DI0); //18 14 26

  if (!LoRa.begin(BAND)) { //868E6 (France)
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }else{
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa succeed!");
  }

  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  power.led_onoff(true);
  delay(500);
  power.led_onoff(false);

  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("hello");  
  LoRa.endPacket();
  Serial.println("sent..");
  power.print_status();
  Serial.println();
  delay(2000);  
}
```

And here is the output i get

```
Power begin
AXP192 Begin PASS
All sensors off
All peripherals off
Powering LoRa
Starting LoRa succeed!

sent..
Voltages:
         DCDC1: 3.30v
         DCDC2: 1.25v
         DCDC3: 3.30v
         LDO2: 3.30v
         LDO3: 2.80v
ChargeCurrent:   0.70A
IPSOUTVoltage:   3.57v
Temp:            15.94°C
TSTemp:          800.00
VbusCurrent:     0.00
VbusVoltage:     0.00
Battery:
         Connected: false
         Charging:  false
         ChargEN :  true
         Voltage:   0.00v
         Inpower:   0.00
         DischgCur: 0.00
         ChargeCur: 0.00
```

I even tried to change the antenna.
I also tried to make the TBeam as receiver, and nothing arrived.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using one t-beam to send and a second to receive. The solution was to cycle power to both boards. Doing a reset or uploading the code does not do the same thing. I spent hours looking at my code and trying different things until I cycled power to both boards. I can finally work on the code for my project. Lilygo documentation is very minimal and some of the example code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

They should work provided the frequencies are the same,

Check if both the T-Beam as well as the LoRa32 modules operate in the same frequency. Lora supports different frequencies. If you check in the links you provided you will see the following code:

```
//433E6 for Asia
//866E6 for Europe
//915E6 for North America
#define BAND 866E6
```

Whereas in your T-Beam code there  is

```
#define BAND  868E6
```

So maybe you have a problem here.